# White spaces at the beginning of XML

Tags: php, xml

I have the followin PHP code that returns an XML:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/xml");
header("Expires:Mon,6 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified:".gmdate("D,d M Y H:i:s")."GMT");
header("Cache-Control:no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control:post-check=0,pre-check=0",false);
header("Pragma:no-cache");
include('database_connection.php');
$category=$_GET['category'];
$city=$_GET['city'];
$country=$_GET['country'];
$dom=new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$node=$dom->createElement("elements");
$parnode=$dom->appendChild($node);
$query="select * from elements where elementId=any(select elementId from citycategoryelements where cityId="
        . "any(select cityId from city where name='$city' and country='$country') and categoryId="
        . "any(select categoryId from categories where name='$category'))";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if(!$result){
echo"Could not successfully run query from DB: ".mysql_error();
exit;
}
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$node=$dom->createElement("element");
$newnode=$parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
$newnode->setAttribute("address",$row['address']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat",$row['lat']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lng",$row['lng']);
$newnode->setAttribute("stars",$row['stars']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

The XML returned looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements><element name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" stars="5"/><element name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" stars="5"/></elements>
```

The problem is that at the beginning of the document there are white spaces and I can't seem to figure out where they come from from the PHP script.

I searched on Stack Owerflow and on other sites for this problem but nothing worked.

If someone faced this situation before and know how to help me it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be something in the saveXML() rather than your posted code.

Comment: Check for any output inside `include('database_connection.php');`.

Comment: There are **two** leading spaces in the XML you posted, is it a typo? Are they actually spaces? (save the XML to a file and open in a hex editor to check)

Comment: @Flosculus-you are right the problem was in database_connection.php, thanks for the help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it is better to include all files before sending the headers.
PHP should throw errors telling you that you can't send headers after output has been sent.

In general, debugging a problem like this is best effected by tracing the code backwards down the stack trace.

Sometimes the most primitive form is debugging is also the most successful.
Checking at various points throughout your code allow you to narrow down the problem:

```
ob_start();

include('some_file.php');

if(strlen(ob_get_clean()) > 0) {
    die('Output dispatched before this point.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping me and also thanks for this advice that will definitely be useful